# Automapper AssertConfigurationIsValid does not check ReverseMap

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

When I create mapping 1->2 and then reverse it, I expect to get the same thing as mapping 2->1 and reversing.  Right?  But `AssertConfigurationIsValid` succeeds in one case, and fails in the other.

For example,

```
public class Basic1
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}

public class Basic2
{
    public string Name;
}


public void TestAutoMapperBasic()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Basic1, Basic2>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ReverseMap();
    });
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

This will succeed?!!!  but if I reverse it, to be `CreateMap<Basic2, Basic1>` then it will fail.

I want `AssertConfigurationIsValid` to actually check **both** directions, not just one direction.  How can I do that?

Comment: see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/940

Comment: This is the expected behavior. ReverseMap is different, it assumes you're literally flattening and un-flattening. For un-flattening, you'd want to assert that the source side is all mapped, not the destination. Reverse map doesn't assume you want to assert anything, since you've already validated the Source -> Destination mapping.

In short, ReverseMap is now "special" and not merely a short cut for two CreateMap calls. [Jimmy Said Here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2327)

Comment: @NaDeRStar, thank you very much for the pointer. That explains it. However, I think  "ReverseMap assumes you are unflattening" is stupid. That is simply **one** use case. There are other use cases that have *nothing* to do with flattening, and in those cases it is very useful to validate both directions. Ah well, it's free anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, as [described here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2327#issuecomment-332209154) by the developer.

> Ah, this is the expected behavior. ReverseMap is different, it
> assumes you're literally flattening and un-flattening. For
> un-flattening, you'd want to assert that the source side is all
> mapped, not the destination. Reverse map doesn't assume you want to
> assert anything, since you've already validated the Source ->
> Destination mapping.
>
> In short, ReverseMap is now "special" and not merely a short cut for
> two CreateMap calls.

If you want to specify that the reverse map should also validate, you can explicitly specify as such:

```cs
config.ReverseMap().ValidateMemberList(MemberList.Destination)
```

You could also create an extension method as a shortcut for this:

```cs
public static IMappingExpression<TDestination, TSource> ReverseMapWithValidation<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mapping)
    => mapping.ReverseMap().ValidateMemberList(MemberList.Destination);
```